# regex: match capture group x or more times

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make my regex capture group only match if it matches 3 or more times. trying this regex `((\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}){3,})`  to match:

```
111-11-6534
111-11-6534
111-11-6534
123-11-6534
123-11-6534
123-11-6534
111-11-6534
```

My regex isn't working obviously. Is there a way to match only if a capture group has `{x}` or more matches?

Comment: Use: `((?:\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}\s*){3,})`

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/X0IgxS/1. The main point is that you need to match what is in between the occurrences of that pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to the nice people in `#regex` on freenode. This accomplishes what I am looking to do: only match if there are 10 or more items, and also match if there are characters before or after the digit string.

`(?:.*?\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}.*(?:\r?\n)?){10,}`